# Datasource to SQL Server does not work in websphere

Tags: sql-server, websphere, datasource

We are using in our project a websphere application server and want to connect to a sql server. In our websphere we have configured a datasource and the testing of the connection in the websphere works. In our deployed application the connection does not work. We get this exception:

```
Caused by: com.ibm.websphere.ce.cm.StaleConnectionException: Single-Sign-On is only supported on Windows. Please specify a user name.DSRA0010E: SQL State = 08001, Error Code = 0
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:56)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:515)
    at com.ibm.websphere.rsadapter.GenericDataStoreHelper.mapExceptionHelper(GenericDataStoreHelper.java:608)
    at com.ibm.websphere.rsadapter.GenericDataStoreHelper.mapException(GenericDataStoreHelper.java:670)
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.AdapterUtil.mapException(AdapterUtil.java:2111)
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.spi.WSRdbDataSource.getPooledConnection(WSRdbDataSource.java:2320)
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.spi.WSManagedConnectionFactoryImpl.createManagedConnection(WSManagedConnectionFactoryImpl.java:1600)
    at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.FreePool.createManagedConnectionWithMCWrapper(FreePool.java:2036)
    at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.FreePool.createOrWaitForConnection(FreePool.java:1713)
    at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.PoolManager.reserve(PoolManager.java:2496)
    at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.ConnectionManager.allocateMCWrapper(ConnectionManager.java:1063)
    at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.ConnectionManager.allocateConnection(ConnectionManager.java:700)
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcDataSource.getConnection(WSJdbcDataSource.java:668)
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcDataSource.getConnection(WSJdbcDataSource.java:635)
    at de.volkswagen.dps.server.core.database.ConnectionFactory.createDatasourceConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:45)
    ... 40 more
```

We use this driver: `jtds-1.2.4.jar` which we got from [here](http://jtds.sourceforge.net/)

Have anybody an idea how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a security issue.

With `Test Connection` a SSO (Single sign on) can be used, but not in the deployed app.

you need to make sure you setup a JAAS authentication alias and configure your Datasource to use it, that alias comtains the username and password to be used for authentication.

Open the Datasource in the admin console and there is a link on the right to create the JAAS alias and tHere are combo boxes to tell the datasource to use it.